# Keras Model.fit Verbose Formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm running Keras model.fit() in Jupyter notebook, and the output is very messy if verbose is set to 1:

```
    Train on 6400 samples, validate on 800 samples
    Epoch 1/200
    2080/6400 [========>.....................] - ETA: 39s - loss: 0.4383 - acc: 0.79 
    - ETA: 34s - loss: 0.3585 - acc: 0.84 - ETA: 33s - loss: 0.3712 - acc: 0.84 
    - ETA: 34s - loss: 0.3716 - acc: 0.84 - ETA: 33s - loss: 0.3675 - acc: 0.84 
    - ETA: 33s - loss: 0.3650 - acc: 0.84 - ETA: 34s - loss: 0.3759 - acc: 0.83 
    - ETA: 34s - loss: 0.3933 - acc: 0.82 - ETA: 34s - loss: 0.3985 - acc: 0.82 
    - ETA: 34s - loss: 0.4057 - acc: 0.82 - ETA: 33s - loss: 0.4071 - acc: 0.81 
    ....
```

As you can see, the ETA, loss, acc outputs kept appending to the log, instead of replacing the original ETA/loss/acc values within the first line, just like how the progress bar works.

How do I fix it it so that only 1 line of progress bar, ETA, loss & acc are shown per epoch? Right now, my cell output has tons of these lines as the training continues.

I'm running Python 3.6.1 on Windows 10, with the following module versions:

```
jupyter                            1.0.0
jupyter-client                     5.0.1
jupyter-console                    5.1.0
jupyter-core                       4.3.0
jupyterthemes                      0.19.0
Keras                              2.2.0
Keras-Applications                 1.0.2
Keras-Preprocessing                1.0.1
tensorflow-gpu                     1.7.0
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can try the Keras-adapted version of the TQDM progress bar library.

- The **original** TQDM library: https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm
- The **Keras version** of TQDM: https://github.com/bstriner/keras-tqdm

The usage instructions can be brought down to:

1. install e.g. per `pip install keras-tqdm` (stable) or `pip install git+https://github.com/bstriner/keras-tqdm.git` (for latest dev-version)
2. import the callback function with `from keras_tqdm import TQDMNotebookCallback`
3. run Keras' `fit` or `fit_generator` with `verbose=0` or `verbose=2` settings, but with a callback to the imported `TQDMNotebookCallback`, e.g. `model.fit(X_train, Y_train, verbose=0, callbacks=[TQDMNotebookCallback()])`

The result:

[image]

Comment: I noticed that in many Keras Jupyter notebooks, their saved model.fit() output logs only showed one output line of loss, acc etc for each epoch, even though they didn't import keras_tqdm, and was just importing tqdm_notebook. Does that mean in certain versions of Keras / Jupyter, this problem does not exist? The output also seems more text-based, like "6400/6400 [==============================] - 53s 8ms/step - loss: 0.5435 - acc: 0.7451 - val_loss: 0.4689 - val_acc: 0.7468"

Answer (score 28):

Took me a while to see this but I just added built-in support for `keras` in `tqdm` (version >= 4.41.0) so you could do:

```
from tqdm.keras import TqdmCallback
...
model.fit(..., verbose=0, callbacks=[TqdmCallback(verbose=2)])
```

This turns off `keras`' progress (`verbose=0`), and uses `tqdm` instead. For the callback, `verbose=2` means separate progressbars for epochs and batches. `1` means clear batch bars when done. `0` means only show epochs (never show batch bars).

Comment: This is an elegant solution

Comment: Flipping awesome - should now be the accepted answer - thank you @casper.dcl

Comment: @casper.dcl - annoyingly this now fails with `AttributeError: 'TqdmCallback' object has no attribute '_implements_train_batch_hooks'` - even with tqdm 4.4.1. The problem must be on the keras side?

Comment: @jtlz2 see workaround [here](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/979#issuecomment-638064271).

Comment: @EliadL Thank you - and I see casper.dcl has now fixed!

Comment: yes `AttributeError: _implements_train_batch_hooks` is fixed in `tqdm>=4.46.1`

Answer (score 0):

One can write his own custom train callback, e.g.

```
class train_print_cb(keras.callbacks.Callback):

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        keys = list(logs.keys())
        watch = keys[0] ## watching the first key, usually the loss         
        print(f'epoch {epoch} {watch}: {logs[watch]:.3f}          ', end = '\r')


model.fit(...verbose = 0, callbacks=[train_print_cb()])
```

Note the print parameter `end = '\r'` at the on_epoch_end function. It means that on terminal and Jupyter notebook the status line (epoch number and watch value) are overwritten when a new status is available. I personally find it convenient.

Further information regarding custom callbacks: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_callback