# keras fit verbose floods cell output in vscode

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, visual-studio-code, verbose

I am facing a similar problem as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52443200/keras-floods-jupyter-cell-output-during-fit-verbose-1). The Keras verbose floods the cell output in VSCode's Jupyter. Similar to this:

`loss: 217.5794 - mean_absolute_error: 11.166 - ETA: 32:42 - loss: 216.9500 - mean_absolute_error: 11.165 - ETA: 32:21 - loss: 216.6378 - mean_absolute_error: 11.164 - ETA: 32:00 - loss: 216.0345 - mean_absolute_error: 11.164 - ETA: 31:41 - loss: 215.6621 - mean_absolute_error: 11.166`

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, This has to do with tqdm version adopted by Keras.

As stated here, [Keras Model.fit Verbose Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52261597/keras-model-fit-verbose-formatting)

use TqdmCallback with verbose=2 for a cleaner output. The above link resolved my problem.